# Code coverage for apex class email alert with template

Tags: unit-test

I am unable to cover the following code which sends email alert with template to customer upon case submission. Please correct my test class and suggest me where I am doing mistakes. Thanks in advance.

APEX CLASS:

```
List<EmailTemplate> temp1 = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE name =: tempName];

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email1 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            email1.setWhatId(this.dummycase.id);
            email1.setTargetObjectId(c.ContactId);
            email1.setTemplateId(temp1.get(0).id);
            email1.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(addrs.id);
            Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r1 =
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email1});
```

TEST CLASS:

```
Profile p = [select id from profile where name='System Administrator'];                
            User u = new User();            
               u.FirstName = 'TestUser';
               u.LastName = 'Test';
               u.Email = 'Testuser@searshc.com';
               u.Username = 'Testuser@searshc.com.devbox';
               u.Alias = 'Tusr';
               u.CommunityNickname = 'Tusrn';
               u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Chicago';
               u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
               u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
               u.ProfileId = p.Id;
               u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';

              insert u;

        System.runAs(u){
            List<Account> acc = new List<Account>{
                         new Account(Name = 'Wayfair',
                                     Category__c = 'Tools'),
                         new Account(Name = 'Mario',
                                     Category__c = 'Garden')};

              insert acc;

            List<Case> cs = new List<Case>{ 
                         new Case( Seller_ID__c = 'a11442',                                                                                               
                                   Send_upc_mail__c = True),
                         new Case( Seller_ID__c = 'b44778',                                                     
                                   Send_upc_mail__c = False) };                                            
                 insert cs;

                  emailmessage em = new emailmessage();
                em.fromaddress = 'Test@test.com';
                em.toaddress = 'test1@test.com';
                em.subject = 'Test Email';
                em.textbody = 'testing';
                em.parentid = cs[0].id;
                test.starttest();
                insert em;
                test.stoptest();
                }
```

Comment: You need to provide more of the surrounding context.

Comment: We are sending auto replies to our customers upon case submission, where it will take contact email address of the customer and send auto email alert.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. We need to see your `Apex` code in a more entire format to even hope to recommend how to cover it.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your test class needs to create all of the objects you need in order to send your email. One thing that's obviously missing is your [emailTemplate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailtemplate.htm). Without creating that, your test class will always fail. You'll also need to assign it in your test class' code (make it available using the same name that your Apex code queries). Similarly, I don't see a query for your OrgWideId that you need to assign to your email.

Your class references a WhatId and a TargetObjectId, yet your test class doesn't. In fact, your test class adds additional parameters not used by your Apex Class that you're testing. Are those merge fields? If not, they should be removed from your test class.

Finally, your test class should assert the results. In your case, you can approach this in a couple of different ways. Sending Email is like performing DML. Email also has it's own limits. I recommend using the limits class to check the available limits before you Send the Email and after you send it, then assert that available limits are one less than before After having sent the email.

Comment: Normally you would use a pre-existing template, I think.

Comment: A template can be created, thus the reason I suggested creating it. In either case, it needs to be available and assigned.